# HttpClient execute keeps giving ConnectTimeoutException

Tags: android, rest, httpclient, http-get, connection-timeout

I have this very big bug in my application that I really can't seem to solve. Whenever I make a rest call via the following code:

```
  HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url + getParams());

  HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
  HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
  HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);

  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

  httpClient.execute(request);
```

I get the error in DDMS:

```
07-15 11:22:47.448: WARN/System.err(973): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to (some ip-address) timed out
```

But sometimes the code works perfect and I receive my data as it should. I also tested the rest server call via a normal webbrowser on my computer and that always gives back my data within 100ms. So what am I doing wrong? I also tested it on another device, but that gives me the same problem. I would be SO glad if somebody could solve my problem :)

Comment: This probably has to do with a slow network (are you using Wi-Fi or 3G?). Try running it in the emulator. You may need to increase the connection timeout and set up a retry mechanism.

Comment: Yeah but with my other apps I can get the requested data all the time. And with one of the phones I am using WiFi, but that one gives me exceptions either. And as far as I know, The httpclient has an automatic retry mechanism?

Comment: Increase the timeout to 20-30 seconds. At times, the line may be busy and hence the timeout.

Comment: Alright, I increased the timeout to 20 seconds:

HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 20000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 20000);

But I still have the same situation, the data gets loaded very rarely and mostly it doesn't receive anything

Comment: Hey Martijn538 Did you find the solution for your issue with timeouts?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the `DefaultHttpClient`. Are you using it asynchronously? Since the `DefaultHttpClient` is not thread-safe, using it in an asynchronous environment might cause a problem. I've had this problem before when my activity started multiple Http connection at the same time and i ended up changing it to use `HttpURLConnection`. You can refer to this site: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html

Answer (score 1):

I having the same issue.

Try using direct IP for your requests. I noticed that Android DNS lookups behave quite weird sometimes. I searched and found this : http://mailinglists.945824.n3.nabble.com/Android-and-reverse-DNS-lookup-issues-td3011461.html .

Dunno if it's relevant or not, i'm still trying to find a workaround. Maybe someone here can take a look and figure it out.

Comment: Had the exact same issue after I changed my hosts-file. A reboot of the phone solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are able to connect using your development machine, Also check the load times. There is a very good chance your timeouts are way too small.

Comment: I changed the timeouts to 20 seconds, still the same problem.. What more can I try? Haven't anybody ran into this problem before?

Comment: Can you access the URL view your dev machine?

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is: sometimes it's loading good and in time and sometimes it doesn't seem to load at all!

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, could be reproduced only when trying to connect using several devices simultaneously and the solution was:

> Instance reboot solved problem with connections.
>   (or just need to restart networking service)

(c) My server/instance admin

Also, there are people who experience similar issues and some other solutions worked for them, for instance:

1. Disable tcp_timestamp
2. Disable tcp_tw_reuse & tcp_tw_recycle
3. Enabled vm save mode in Android manifest: android:vmSafeMode="true"

---

- [Android http connection - multiple devices cannot connect the same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623779/android-http-connection-multiple-devices-cannot-connect-the-same-server)
- https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/182935/httpclient-behaviour-ok-on-3g-but-faces-timeout-under-wifi-for-2-or-more-devices
- https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/903
- https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1037
- https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1518