# Android - API Requests

Tags: android, ios, http, ssl, certificate

I develop an app which is also on iPhone. Problem is with api requests.
I setup the timeouts for all requests. Sometimes it occurs kind a breaks from 30 - 60 second.
It looks like this that app does couple request and than break, all the time timeouts, after about 45 second everything ok.

I don't know if this is server issue or android.

This problem doesn't occur on iPhone with IOS 5, but also apear on IOS 4.

All request are SSL and because of not trusted certificate I use this class:

```
public class HttpSupport 
{
//********************************************
// Two methods to remove the "certificate" issue.
//********************************************

public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory 
{
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException 
    {
        super(truststore);

        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException 
            {

            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException 
            {

            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }
}

public SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory()
{
    try 
    {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        return sf;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public DefaultHttpClient getNewHttpClient() 
{
    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        int timeoutConnection = 3000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, timeoutConnection);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        int timeoutSocket = 5000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, timeoutSocket);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I found something like this, but I don't know if this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705170/httpclient-execute-keeps-giving-connecttimeoutexception Has someone ever occurred the same issue like me?